# Not enough points to flag this question for migration

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I was googling some issue and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025734/applescript-finder-view-options-in-mojave-background-color) question that is exactly what I was looking for (sadly no answers though). I feel like this question is more fitted to the Apple exchange, since it's not really a programming issue, but macOS issue. However I don't have enough points to neither migrate nor flag the question, so I'm posting it here.

Sorry if it don't belong here, still new to this stuff.

Comment: It does actually belong here as a question :). Now, that being said, Apple exchange isn't part of the normal migration path, it would need to be a custom mod flag (or, as Makoto said, seems like this doesn't even deserve the migration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[automator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automator) has about 820 questions in it, and the questions we want concern themselves around actual code used to interact with the automator.

The thing that the OP is missing there is that code.  Migrating it over wouldn't get them a solution since it'd be unclear to a Mac enthusiast what they're trying to accomplish.

It'd be better to flag it for being unclear anyway, since the code is lacking and this *sorely* needs that context.